# Promotion: Automatically add certain product to cart for free

Tags: addtocart, promotions

Is it (and if so, how is it) possible to create the following promotion in Magento?

If a certain product item is added to the cart, another certain product shall be added to cart automatically and the price of this second product shall be set to 0.

Thanks a lot for helping!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create an observer for `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
    <observer name="CustomObserver" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CustomObserver" />
</event>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/CustomObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class AddCharges implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_cart;

    public function __construct( \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository, \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart ){
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_cart = $cart;
    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getData('product');


        if($product->getId() != ID ){
            $params = array(
                'product' => ID,
                'qty' => $product->getQty(),
                'price' => 0
            );
            $_product = $this->_productRepository->getById( ID );
            $this->_cart->addProduct($_product,$params);
            $this->_cart->save();
        }

    }
}
```

Note that the **ID** is the second products id here.